# Phaser 3: How to stop scene?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

This is a code from one of Codecademy's practice. I am trying to end scene when the option text says Play again. Basically what I want is that a specific option will allow me to exit the scene and enter a new one. (ie when the game is over)
I tried using

```
if (optionText==="Play again"){
        optionBox.on('pointerup', function() {
          this.scene.stop("game")
      
      })}
```

I have commented out the code at line 116

but it only crashed the code.

```
let gameState = {}

function preload () {
  // load in background and characters
  this.load.image('bg',     'https://content.codecademy.com/projects/learn-phaser/cyoa/background.png');
  this.load.image('knight', 'https://content.codecademy.com/projects/learn-phaser/cyoa/knight.png');
  this.load.image('orc',    'https://content.codecademy.com/projects/learn-phaser/cyoa/orc.png');
  this.load.image('wizard', 'https://content.codecademy.com/projects/learn-phaser/cyoa/wizard.png');
}
function create(){
  gameState.background=this.add.image(0,0,"bg")
  gameState.background.setOrigin(0,0);
  gameState.character=renderCharacter(this,"knight");
  initializePage(this);
  const firstPage=fetchPage(1);
  displayPage(this,firstPage)
}
function renderCharacter(scene,key){
  if (gameState.character){
    gameState.character.destroy();}
    gameState.character=scene.add.image(270,340,key);
        gameState.character.setOrigin(0.5,1);
    gameState.character.setScale(0.7); }



function initializePage(scene) {
  // create options list and background
  // and saves them into gameState

  if (!gameState.options) {
    // create options list
    // if it doesn't exist
    gameState.options = [];
  }

  if (!gameState.narrative_background) {
    // create narrative background
    // if it doesn't exist
    gameState.narrative_background = scene.add.rectangle(10, 360, 430, 170, 0x000);
  gameState.narrative_background.setOrigin(0, 0);
  }
}

function destroyPage() {
  // wipe out narrative text and options

  if (gameState.narrative) {
    // destroy narrative if it exists
    gameState.narrative.destroy();
  }

  for (let option of gameState.options) {
    // destroy options if they exist
    option.optionBox.destroy();
    option.optionText.destroy();
  }
}

function displayPage(scene, page) {
  renderCharacter(scene,page.character);
  const narrativeStyle = { fill: '#ffffff', fontStyle: 'italic', align: 'center', wordWrap: { width: 340 }, lineSpacing: 8};
  
  // display general page character
  // & narrative here:
  gameState.narrative = scene.add.text(65, 380, page.narrative, narrativeStyle);

  // for-loop creates different options

  // need the index i for spacing the boxes
  for (let i=0; i<page.options.length; i++) {
    let option = page.options[i];

    // color in the option box
    const optionBox = scene.add.rectangle(40 + i * 130, 470, 110, 40, 0xb39c0e, 0)
    optionBox.strokeColor = 0xb39c0e;
    optionBox.strokeWeight = 2;
    optionBox.strokeAlpha = 1;
    optionBox.isStroked = true;
    optionBox.setOrigin(0, 0)
    

    // add in the option text
    const baseX = 40 + i * 130;
    const optionText = scene.add.text(baseX, 480, option.option, { fontSize:14, fill: '#b39c0e', align: 'center', wordWrap: {width: 110}});
    const optionTextBounds = optionText.getBounds()

    // centering each option text
    optionText.setX(optionTextBounds.x + 55 - (optionTextBounds.width / 2));
    optionText.setY(optionTextBounds.y + 10 - (optionTextBounds.height / 2));

    // add in gameplay functionality
    optionBox.setInteractive()
    // for options here

optionBox.on('pointerout', function() {
 this.optionBox.setStrokeStyle(1, 0xb38c03, 1);
this.optionText.setColor('#b39c0e');},  {optionBox, optionText })
  optionBox.on('pointerover', function() {
 this.optionBox.setStrokeStyle(2, 0xffe014, 1);this.optionText.setColor('#ffe014');}
, { optionBox, optionText })
    optionBox.on('pointerup',function(){
      const newPage=this.option.nextPage;
      if (newPage!==undefined){
        destroyPage()
        displayPage(scene,fetchPage(newPage));
      }

    },{option})

 gameState.options.push({
    optionBox,optionText
  })
    
  }
  /* this did NOT work
    if (optionText==="Play again"){
        optionBox.on('pointerup', function() {
          this.scene.stop("game")
      
      })}*/
}

const config = {
  type: Phaser.WEBGL,
  parent: 'phaser-game',
  backgroundColor: 0xfea0fd,
  width: 450,
  height: 550,
  scene: {
    preload,
    create,
  }
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function fetchPage(page) {


   const pages = [
     {
      character: 'orc',
      page: 1,
      narrative: 'Orc: Hello?',
      options: [
        { option: 'Say Hi',   nextPage: 2 },
        { option: 'Play again',   nextPage: 41 },
      ]
    },



  return pages.find(function(e) { if(e.page == page) return e });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you shorted the code for us, so ignoreing the missing `]` on line 150 and the missing page number `41` in the `pages` constant on line 141+.

I would say the problem is **not** the `this.scene.stop("game")`, although I would just use `this.scene.stop()`, if you want the stop the current `scene` ([in to a Reference](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/scenemanager/#stop-scene) ).

You can see the problem, if you uncomment the code and check the browser console, an error like:

> *"...Uncaught ReferenceError: optionText is not defined..."*

should be visible. That indicates the real issue, it is that  `optionText` ist not defined. Without diving to deep into your code here are some fixes to get it to work:

- Move the whole block into the for loop. (just above the `}` on line 115)
- change `if(optionText=== "Play again")` to `if(optionText.text === "Play again")`since  `optionText` is a `text` object not a string.
- Add a the `scene` object as context to the `optionBox.on('pointerup',...` eventlistener
  like this:

  ```
    optionBox.on('pointerup', function () {
        this.scene.stop("game")
    }, scene)
  ```

and it should "work".

> **btw.:** If you have Errors/Problems/... with html/javscript always check the browser console, this can help you find the error much faster.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! I tried it and it worked like a charm! One question though-- what's the point of the scene object?

Comment: the `scene` object is more or less the screen where everything is drawn. Check out this short examples on the official phaser page: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/scenes, they explain function of the scene object abit better, than I ever could. :)